# SQL change boolean to word in a select statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a boolean i grab in a sql command to send a word instead of 1/0 or true/false.

The code i am using is below, and where it grabs p.premium, i want it to see if it a 0 or a 1. An if its a 1 change the value to "paid" and if its a 0 the change the value to "free".

iv tried case statement but it failed haha.

```
SELECT      P.Id AS Ref
            ,P.Listed AS Listed
            ,Convert(Date, Convert(VarChar, P.ListedDate, 12)) AS DateListed
            ,P.Premium AS Type
            ,P.PostCode AS London
            ,Convert(Date, Convert(VarChar,(SELECT TOP 1 MoveInDate FROM PropertyTenant WHERE P.Id = PropertyId ORDER BY Id), 12)) AS MoveInDate

             FROM [Database].[dbo].[Property] AS P
```

Comment: If you tried a `CASE` statement that failed, you should really have included that attempt in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE WHEN P.Premium = 1 THEN 'Paid' ELSE 'Free' END AS IsPaid`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use [IIF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx):

```
IIF ( P.Premium = 1, 'true value!', 'false value!' )
```

Comment: This does only work in SQL Server 2012 and newer though.